# Allowing Copy/Paste for XamDataGrid across application

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, xamdatagrid

I'm working on an application that had many infrgistics XamDataGrids. I'd like to at least provide Copy to clipboard abilities on them. This can easily be achieved in the XAML for each grid, with:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding}" >
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AllowClipboardOperations="Copy"/>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

However, I would like all XamDataGrids in the application to allow this Copy to clipboard feature. I thought styling would be the answer, but for some reason, this does not work:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:FieldLayoutSettings}">            
    <Setter Property="AllowClipboardOperations" Value="Copy" />
</Style>
```

I've tried many variations on the above, but nothing seems to take, and there are no error messages. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but perhaps you require the fully qualified name as below: (including the **XamDataGrid.**)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings}"> 
    <Setter Property="AllowClipboardOperations" Value="Copy" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I just ran across it.

Anyway, the TargetType of your style will be XamDataGrid.
The property you are setting is FieldLayoutSettings.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDp:XamDataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="FieldLayoutSettings">
        <Setter.Value>
            <igDp:FieldLayoutSettings AllowClipboardOperations="Copy"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this style defined in a place (like App.xaml) where every XamDataGrid can inherit it?

Have you tried defining this style in the same XAML file as a XamDataGrid that might use it?  I would start by seeing if you could make this work as a local style in one specific place.

Comment: yeah, it's defined in the same xaml file where the XamDataGrid is instantiated.